# SyntaxError: Unexpected token export while running tests in Jest with components having amcharts4

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, amcharts, amcharts4

Geeting error: Unexpected token export while running tests in Jest with components having amcharts4

```
 export { System, system } from "./.internal/core/System";
    ^^^^^^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token export

    > 1 | import * as am4core from "@amcharts/amcharts4/core";
        | ^
      2 | import * as am4charts from "@amcharts/amcharts4/charts";
      3 | import * as am4maps from "@amcharts/amcharts4/maps";
      4 | import am4geodata_worldLow from "@amcharts/amcharts4-geodata/worldLow";
```

"jest": "24.9.0"
"@amcharts/amcharts4": "^4.10.19"
"typescript": "^3.9.5"

Following is jest config in the package.json file :(Using create-react-app for the project & ejected it)

```
"jest": {
    "roots": [
      "<rootDir>/src"
    ],
    
    "collectCoverageFrom": [
      "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "!src/**/*.d.ts"
    ],
    "setupFiles": [
      "react-app-polyfill/jsdom",
      "<rootDir>\\src\\__mocks__\\dom.js",
      "<rootDir>\\src\\__mocks__\\reactrouter.js"
    ],
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect"
    ],
    "testMatch": [
      "<rootDir>/src/**/__tests__/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "<rootDir>/src/**/*.{spec,test}.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}"
    ],
    "testEnvironment": "jest-environment-jsdom-fourteen",
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
      "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "node_modules/(?!@amcharts/amcharts4/)",
      "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
    ],
    "modulePaths": [
      "<rootDir>/src/",
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/"
    ],
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|scss)$": "<rootDir>/src/__mocks__/styleMock.js"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "web.js",
      "js",
      "web.ts",
      "ts",
      "web.tsx",
      "tsx",
      "json",
      "web.jsx",
      "jsx",
      "node"
    ],
    "watchPlugins": [
      "jest-watch-typeahead/filename",
      "jest-watch-typeahead/testname"
    ]
}
```

Comment: @Subrato Patnaik added

Comment: Sorry, could you also  share jest.config.js?

Comment: @SubratoPatnaik added

Comment: In transformIgnorePattern, could you try with this `'node_modules[/\\\\](?!@amcharts[/\\\\]amcharts4)'` and let me know if that works?

Comment: didn't work..same error

Comment: just know read about [using amcharts with jest](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/getting-started/using-typescript-or-es6/#Using_amCharts_with_Jest). It seems not possible as of now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Cause:** `babel-jest` uses babel configuration that is loaded based on the location of the file that is going to be transformed. After ejecting create-react-app your package.json probably contains:

```
"babel": {
  "presets": [
    "react-app"
  ]
}
```

which makes import/export statements work for your files, but @amcharts/amcharts4 does not have that setting in its package.json nor does it have .babelrc and so no import/export transformation takes place.

**Solution:** You can update your Jest config to transform @amcharts in a more specific way:

1. Add relevant babel plugin: `npm install -D @babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs`
2. Update jest config in your package.json - redirect @amcharts transformation to custom transformer. *(I also changed `transformIgnorePatterns` so that they work for Windows.)*

```
"transform": {
  "@amcharts[/\\\\].+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/babelTransformImportExport.js",
  "^.+\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$": "babel-jest",
  "^.+\\.css$": "<rootDir>/config/jest/cssTransform.js",
  "^(?!.*\\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx|css|json)$)": "<rootDir>/config/jest/fileTransform.js"
},
"transformIgnorePatterns": [
  "node_modules[/\\\\](?!@amcharts[/\\\\]amcharts4[/\\\\])",
  "^.+\\.module\\.(css|sass|scss)$"
],
```

3. Create `config/jest/babelTransformImportExport.js`:

```
const babelJest = require("babel-jest");

module.exports = babelJest.createTransformer({
  plugins: [require.resolve("@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs")],
  babelrc: false,
  configFile: false,
});
```

Tests should be running now.

**Edit:** As Subrato Patnaik mentioned ([using amcharts with jest](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/getting-started/using-typescript-or-es6/#Using_amCharts_with_Jest)), amcharts use APIs such as SVGPathElement which aren't yet available in Jest test environment (JSDOM - issue [#2128](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/issues/2128)). In other words, your tests won't probably work, if you're using standard mounting. But they *might* work if you are using e.g. [enzyme](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/) and its shallow rendering.

If you don't use enzyme or it doesn't work, then as the last resort, you can try to simply define missing APIs in a minimalistic way and see whether it is sufficient:

1. Change `setupFiles` in jest config to:

```
"setupFiles": [
  "react-app-polyfill/jsdom",
  "<rootDir>/config/jest/setup.js"
],
```

2. Create `config/jest/setup.js`:

```
class SVGGraphicsElement extends SVGElement {}
class SVGGeometryElement extends SVGGraphicsElement {}
class SVGPathElement extends SVGGeometryElement {}

Object.assign(global, {
  SVGGraphicsElement,
  SVGGeometryElement,
  SVGPathElement,
});
```

**PS:** If you are using pnpm instead of npm/yarn, then you will need to update `transformIgnorePatterns` to:

```
"node_modules[/\\\\](?!(|\\.pnpm[/\\\\]@amcharts.*node_modules[/\\\\])@amcharts[/\\\\]amcharts4[/\\\\])",
```

otherwise the old regexp would match (and therefore ignore) paths such as `node_modules/.pnpm/@amcharts+amcharts4@4.10.21/node_modules/@amcharts/amcharts4/core.js`

Comment: Getting this error now: ReferenceError: SVGPathElement is not defined

Comment: Edited my answer and described what you can do about that.

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttributeNS' of undefined. After your updated answer, getting this error.

Comment: @AbhishekRanjan, is the solution solved your problem, I am also facing similar issue with different module